# Graphite showing 1/6 the points sent

Tags: graphite, statsd

I have a simple Statsd -> Carbon -> Graphite back end setup for one of my processes.

Graphite is configured very simply at 60s:1440m (1 minute accuracy for 24h), and the counter I'm using is just summed up. Nothing fancy done there.

However, it's only displaying a single 10s segment of every minute and I can't seem to figure out why. If I send one statsd packet every minute, I have to send it at :50-:59 of the minute, or it gets overwritten. Sending packets once every 10s means only one of those packets will get saved for storage. I think it's something to do with a simple config option, but haven't had any luck figuring it out thus far. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. Turns out the Statsd backend service was sending aggregated packets to Graphite every 10s, while my Graphite config was set on 60s accuracy.

Comment: Correct, see https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/graphite.md#correlation-with-statsds-flush-interval for more info.